# How to fix relative coordinates on svg.path tikz library

Tags: tikz-pgf, svg

There seems to be a bug or error when using relative commands. In my case, I found an instance where drawing a smooth curve will draw the curve wrongly.

Check the following cases (the first is full relative, and the last one is full absolute), where the relative use of the commands draw erroneously, while the absolute ones are working as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\begin{document}
  % Original
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw svg "M 256 8 C 119 8 8 119 8 256 s 111 248 248 248 s 248 -111 248 -248 S 393 8 256 8 z";
  \end{tikzpicture}
  % Mix of relative
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw svg "M 256 8 C 119 8 8 119 8 256 s 111 248 248 248 S 504 393 504 256 S 393 8 256 8 z";
  \end{tikzpicture}
  % Mix of relative
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw svg "M 256 8 C 119 8 8 119 8 256 S 119 504 256 504 s 248 -111 248 -248 S 393 8 256 8 z";
  \end{tikzpicture}
  % Full absolute
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw svg "M256 8 C 119 8 8 119 8 256 S 119 504 256 504 S 504 393 504 256 S 393 8 256 8 z";
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the definition of `s` operator

> ```
> \pgfparserdef{svgpath}{all}{the letter s}
> {
>   \pgf@lib@svg@finish@prev
>   \pgf@lib@svg@read@nums{4}{\pgf@lib@svg@curveto@rel@smooth}
> }
>
> \def\pgf@lib@svg@curveto@rel@smooth{%
>   \ifnum\pgf@lib@svg@count=0\relax% nothing read
>   \else%
>     % Draw curve
>     % Compute first control point
>     \ifx\pgf@lib@svg@bezier@last\pgfutil@empty%
>       \def\pgf@lib@svg@first@cp{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}
>     \else
>       \def\pgf@lib@svg@first@cp{
>         \pgfpointadd
>         {\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}
>         {\pgfpointdiff
>           {\pgf@lib@svg@bezier@last}
>           {\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}
>         }
>       }
>     \fi
>     \pgfpathcurveto
>     {\pgf@lib@svg@first@cp}
>     {\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{0}pt}{\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{1}pt}}}%
>     {\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{2}pt}{\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{3}pt}}}%
>     % Clear quadratic last point and save new last control point:
>     \let\pgf@lib@svg@quad@last=\pgfutil@empty%
>     \pgf@process{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{2}pt}{\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{3}pt}}}
>     \edef\pgf@lib@svg@bezier@last{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}%
>     % update
>     \advance\pgf@lib@svg@last@x by\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{2}pt%
>     \advance\pgf@lib@svg@last@y by\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{3}pt%
>     % Go on
>     \pgf@lib@svg@read@nums{4}{\pgf@lib@svg@curveto@rel@smooth}
>   \fi
> }
> ```

The following line (currently the line 386 of `pgflibrarysvg.path.code.tex`

> ```
> \pgf@process{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{2}pt}{\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{3}pt}}}
> \edef\pgf@lib@svg@bezier@last{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}%
> ```

is wrong. This is because `\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{2}` and `{3}` is the endpoint of the previous curve. But the standard says that it should remember the second control point of the previous curve. If you change the numbers into `{0}` and `{1}` it will work as expected.

(I suspect that that line is copied from line 300, while in the `C` operator the `{2}` and `{3}` do mean the second control point.)

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\makeatletter

\def\pgf@lib@svg@curveto@rel@smooth{%
  \ifnum\pgf@lib@svg@count=0\relax% nothing read
  \else%
    % Draw curve
    % Compute first control point
    \ifx\pgf@lib@svg@bezier@last\pgfutil@empty%
      \def\pgf@lib@svg@first@cp{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}
    \else
      \def\pgf@lib@svg@first@cp{
        \pgfpointadd
        {\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}
        {\pgfpointdiff
          {\pgf@lib@svg@bezier@last}
          {\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}
        }
      }
    \fi
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgf@lib@svg@first@cp}
    {\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{0}pt}{\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{1}pt}}}%
    {\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{2}pt}{\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{3}pt}}}%
    % Clear quadratic last point and save new last control point:
    \let\pgf@lib@svg@quad@last=\pgfutil@empty%
    \pgf@process{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@last@x}{\pgf@lib@svg@last@y}}{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{0}pt}{\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{1}pt}}} %%%%%% fixing this line
    \edef\pgf@lib@svg@bezier@last{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}%
    % update
    \advance\pgf@lib@svg@last@x by\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{2}pt%
    \advance\pgf@lib@svg@last@y by\pgf@lib@svg@get@num{3}pt%
    % Go on
    \pgf@lib@svg@read@nums{4}{\pgf@lib@svg@curveto@rel@smooth}
  \fi
}


\begin{document}
  % Original
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw svg "M 256 8 C 119 8 8 119 8 256 s 111 248 248 248 s 248 -111 248 -248 S 393 8 256 8 z";
  \end{tikzpicture}
  % Mix of relative
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw svg "M 256 8 C 119 8 8 119 8 256 s 111 248 248 248 S 504 393 504 256 S 393 8 256 8 z";
  \end{tikzpicture}
  % Mix of relative
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw svg "M 256 8 C 119 8 8 119 8 256 S 119 504 256 504 s 248 -111 248 -248 S 393 8 256 8 z";
  \end{tikzpicture}
  % Full absolute
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw svg "M256 8 C 119 8 8 119 8 256 S 119 504 256 504 S 504 393 504 256 S 393 8 256 8 z";
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```